# How to use the cat command to find a specific word in a textfile

Tags: command-line, text-processing, cat

I did some research but I was unable to find anything to help, I need to find the word "war" in a text file, I know that I can use the `cat` command, but I need to modify it somehow, can someone help?

Comment: I am pretty sure I saw a question like this before. What is the assignment?

Comment: Not an assignment, just trying to get used to working with a few basic commands, I've used Ubuntu all my life, but I've only just started exploring the Terminal, always been afraid of braking it somehow xD

Answer (score 16):

You can do it by `grep`. You do not need `cat` for that.

```
grep -w war file_name
```

You can use `cat` too, if you like

```
cat file_name | grep -w war
```

but it is longer.

Comment: I tried this, and now it's not letting me do any commands, but I can type stuff, how do I get back to my command line?

Comment: Press Ctrl+C probably ;-)

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of something. I can't imagine nobody asked it.